# React native parsing data

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Hi everyone i'm newbie in react native and i'm stuck to pass my data to my second page in via my api i get only one message my token for the first log and undefined and i don't understand why
if you could explain me why my day will be better thanks :)

````
    const SignIn = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState();
  const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);


  const onCheck = async () => {
    // console.log(userPassword, userEmail);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'API',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': `application/json`,
          }),
          body: JSON.stringify({email: userEmail, password: userPassword}),
        },
      );

      const json = await response.json();
      const token = json.data.access_token;
      const getMe = await fetch(
        `API`,
        {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': `application/json`,
          },
        },
      );
      const jsonMe = await getMe.json(token);
      const data = jsonMe.data;

      
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
      console.log(token);
      console.log(jsonMe.data);
      navigation.push('HrProfile', token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };```
````

Answer (score 0):

so i hope it's could help some dev
In this form you must pass your token inside headers i tried with authorization up the headers but it stupid
oh and never use in asynchronous function await + .then because await already wait a response so it's useless to call wait + wait
enjoy ;)

```
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState();
  const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 
  const onCheck = async () => {
    // console.log(userPassword, userEmail);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'Your api[for example /login] ',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': `application/json`,
          }),
          body: JSON.stringify({email: userEmail, password: userPassword}),
        },
      );

      const json = await response.json();
      const token = json.data.access_token;
      const getMe = await fetch(YourApi forother example /getMe or other
        ``,
        {
          method: 'GET',

          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Accept: `application/json`,
            'Content-Type': `application/json`,
          },
        },
      );
      const jsonMe = await getMe.json();
      const data = jsonMe.data;

      //Faire la requette ici pour le get me qui va me donner
      // je récupère le token pour pouvoir l'envoyer dans le local storage
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
      console.log(token);
      console.log(jsonMe);
      console.log(data);
      navigation.push('HrProfile', token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```